# How are Speech-to-Text and Video Intelligence SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION related?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api, video-intelligence-api

My goal is to process several videos using a speech-to-text model.

Google confusingly has two products that seem to do the same thing.

What are the major differences between these offering?

1. Google Cloud Speech-to-Text: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics

   - Speech-to-Text has an "enhanced video" model for interpreting the audio.
2. Google Video Intelligence: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/feature-speech-transcription

   - VI has the option to request a `SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION` feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two are the input used. Speech to Text API only accepts audio inputs while Video Intelligence accepts video inputs.

As mentioned in your question **"Speech to Text has an enhance video model"**, it means that it has a model that is designed to transcribe audio that originated from video files. Meaning the original file was in video, then converted to audio. As seen in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/video-model), the video was converted to audio prior to transcribing it.

I suggest to use Video Intelligence API if you would like to directly transcribe the audio content into text. You can follow this [tutorial on how to transcribe text](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/transcription) using Video Intelligence API.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the same model is being used on the backend? Can I expect very similar accuracy?

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO Yes it is using the same model in the back end. Yes, you should expect similar accuracy.